facing runtime error in gcp-dataflow pipeline
I am trying to develop a simple dataflow pipeline that will read string data from a pub/sub topic called 'iot' continuously, process it in a simple way , and save it in a required schema format to a firestore collection 'vehicle-tracking'.
I am sending data to the pub/sub topic and can even view the new data using a subscription, showing that the topic is receiving data, but pipeline doesnt seem to process any data, or it gives a nasty runtime error.
I decided to use dataflow as it provides the streaming feature and divided my pipeline into 3 stages:

Ingest from pub/sub topic
Window the continuous data into a duration of one minute(I have commented this out for now- when I run the pipeline with this nothing happens:)
For each window, store elements into firestore schema

Wrote a maven java project for the same.
Currently am using a free trial account on gcp, any help would be appreciated as I am a complete beginner!
StreamtoFirestore.java
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutures;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.WriteResult;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;

import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.FixedWindows;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.Window;
import org.joda.time.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class StreamtoFirestore {
    public static class VehicleData {
        private String vehicle_id;
        private double latitude;
        private double longitude;
        private double temp;
        private long timestamp;

        // getters and setters


        public String getVehicle_id() {
            return vehicle_id;
        }

        public void setVehicle_id(String vehicle_id) {
            this.vehicle_id = vehicle_id;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public double getTemp() {
            return temp;
        }

        public void setTemp(double temp) {
            this.temp = temp;
        }

        public long getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
            Map<String, Object> firestoreSchemaMap = new HashMap<>();
            firestoreSchemaMap.put("vehicle_id", vehicle_id);
            firestoreSchemaMap.put("latitude", latitude);
            firestoreSchemaMap.put("longitude", longitude);
            firestoreSchemaMap.put("temp", temp);
            ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
            firestoreSchemaMap.put("timestamp", Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(zone).toString());
            return firestoreSchemaMap;
        }
    }

    // Convert JSON string to VehicleData
    private static VehicleData convertToVehicleData(String json) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, VehicleData.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log errors -> replace later
            System.out.println("Error!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class WriteToFirestoreDoFn extends DoFn<String, Void> {
        private transient Firestore firestore;

        @Setup
        public void setup() {
            firestore = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        }

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String json = c.element();
            System.out.println(json);
            VehicleData data = convertToVehicleData(json);

            if(data!=null) {

                // Populate the Firestore map with the data
                Map<String, Object> firestoreData = data.toMap();

                // Generate a unique document ID using UUID
                String uniqueDocumentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                // Define Firestore document path with unique ID
                String documentPath = "vehicle-tracking/" + uniqueDocumentId;
                // Firestore write operation
                ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = firestore.document(documentPath).set(firestoreData);

                // Handle asynchronous result
                ApiFutures.addCallback(future, new ApiFutureCallback<WriteResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        // Log the error
                        System.err.println("Error writing to Firestore: " + t.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(WriteResult result) {
                        // Optionally log success
                        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to Firestore: " + result.getUpdateTime());
                    }
                }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // can extend this to create a more generic pipeline with command line arguments
        // arguments for local testing/cloud testing , maven profiles
        // create an options class
        /*PipelineOptions myPipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(PipelineOptions.class);

*/
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        options.setProject("clean-doodad-428805-i9");
        options.setRegion("asia-east1");
        options.setStreaming(true);
        options.setGcpCredential(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault());
        options.setTempLocation("gs://dataflow-upamanyu/temp/");
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        // read from pub/sub and process from dataflow and send to firestore

        // Step 1. subscribe from pub/sub pull all unacknowledged messages
        p.apply("Read from Pub/Sub IOT Topic", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic("projects/clean-doodad-428805-i9/topics/iot"))

                // Step 2. divide into windows of size 1 minute
                //.apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))

        // save to firestore asynchronously
        .apply(" Transform and Write to Firestore DB",ParDo.of(new WriteToFirestoreDoFn()));

        // run dataflow job

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

}


My pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>dataflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <beam.version>2.57.0</beam.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target> <!-- Use the latest stable version -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Beam SDK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Cloud Dataflow Runner -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Cloud Pub/Sub -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Google Cloud Firestore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson Databind (for JSON parsing, if needed) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version> <!-- Latest stable version -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4 Implementation -->
        <!-- Logback Classic for SLF4J implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>

My pipeline is running but is getting a runtime error :
pipeline error in dataflow console
Currently am using a free trial account on gcp, any help would be appreciated as I am a complete beginner!

My schema for pub/sub received message is
{
"vehicle_id": (string),
"latitude", "longitude", "temp": (double)
"timestamp": (long avro millis)
}
and my firestore schema is the same but timestamp stored as zonedatetime string

Are you using LeastRequestLoadBalancerProvider somewhere in your code ? I don't see it being used by Beam based on a quick search.

It could also be a dependency mismatch. Please make sure that you are using correct dependencies for the Firestore client library and there is not conflict. Alternatively, consider using the Beam provided Firestore connector: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/firestore/FirestoreIO.html

no idea where LeastRequestLoadBalancerProvider is being invoked to be honest  Can you help me with the beam firestore connector part? I tried using firestore.v1().write() but my IDE was giving me errors

with logging I can see the error comes from the firestore line:
firestore = firestoreOptions.getService();

@chamikara It was a dependency issue; the pipeline is working now. I added a BOM and dependency conflicts with firestore seemed to be resolved. I am reworking the pipeline part where a new entry is added to see if I don't have to create my own unique id for the document. Thank you so much!
